# Is Windows Firewall active on OpenVPN connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, openvpn, internet-security

(This applies to "private" Internet browsing through a VPN such as privateinternetaccess.com)

If I connect to a VPN using OpenVPN client on my Windows 7 box, will the Windows firewall be active inside the tunnel?

IOW, will I have some degree of protection for incoming requests through the VPN itself (malicious users also on the VPN)?

I there a block diagram that would explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Windows will request you define the type of connection and depding on your selection will apply default configuration rules.